Is the GEE model an appropriate approach for this study?
I have the following data structure (longitudinal data). Over a period of several months, multiple tests (such as a vocabulary exam, a game exam, and a math exam) are administered to assess brain function. The question is that which one of these tests has
more ability to predict the outcome variable which is disease progression across all time points. So I was wondering if GEE can be a appropriate method to apply
ID    TIME     TEST1    TEST2   TEST3   outcome
1      0         23      5        2       1
1      1         22      4        1       0
1      2         10      3        3       1 
2      0         2       12       11      0
2      1         13      4        12      1
2      2         14      5        12      1


I’m surprised to see disease progression as a binary variable (minimum information, power, and precision).  Is there not a higher-resolution measurement available?  What’s needed is not progression but current severity.  A binary outcome will require you to have an incredibly large sample size.

@Frank Harrell, Thank you so much for your comment. As there are three independent variables in this study; adopting the rule of thumb, can we consider min (event, non-event)= 60 samples for this study or is still insufficient?

You need 96 independent subjects just to estimate the intercept.  This stems from binary Y being minimally informative.

@Frank Harrell, thanks so much. It means that regardless of the technique used (cox regression or GEE), if there are three continuous independent variables in the model and the result is binary, we require around 96+3*20 (or 15 based on your recommendation). Am I right?

That’s close.  Richard Riley at all have a more accurate, formal way to go about this in the univariate (non-longitudinal) case: https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/sim.7992

Yes, that should not be a problem. Since you have longitudinal data with a binary outcome and clustered observations (within an individual), you just need a model that can deal with this, which is exactly what GEE does (with a logit link on your binary outcome).
Another popular choice might be a (Generalized linear) mixed model (GLMM). The main difference between the two lies in the interpretation: the GLMM will tell you something about the subject-specific effects of your covariates on the outcome, while the GEE will tell you something about the population averaged effects.
Note that they have many more (sometimes subtle) differences, for example in case of missing data, GLMM is valid under a MAR assumption, while GEE needs the stronger MCAR assumption or some missing data handling techniques. Also, they differ in the estimation procedure for example, but your main reason for choosing one over the other should involve the choice of interpretation you want for your research.
If you have further trouble or doubts about specifying the model, you may always reach out!

Thank you very much for your time and suggestions. I have two more inquiries, if you don't mind. I was wondering if GEE can deal with correlated explanatory variables (when indep variables are correlated), because in this study, the tests are assessing brain functionality, and they are probably correlated. The second question concerns the existence of a time-dependent covariate in the model. Can we still apply GEE when the test variables are time dependent?

Yes, mixed models (and GEE) are specially made for longitudinal (and clustered) data, so it is certainly possible to include covariates that vary with time. For the correlation between explanatory variables, this just sounds as a multicollinearity problem to me... This is a general problem, which can occur in complex mixed models, but also in simple linear regression models. GEE and mixed models are not made to handle this, but there are other methods for dealing with this (e.g. measure how much they are correlated, calculate VIF, mabye leave one out and look at diagnostic changes, ...)

@
Mathemagician777,  thanks so much for the comments. Based on the following publication https://support.sas.com/resources/papers/proceedings15/3252-2015.pdf it seems that GEE method is not assured to have consistent estimators when using time-dependent covariates.

@
Mathemagician777,
Also in the following link https://mbounthavong.com/blog/tag/time-varying+covariates, it is mentioned that Conventional methods to perform longitudinal data analysis such as linear mixed effects models and generalized estimating equations models are capable of handling time-varying covariates. However, in the case of a time-varying elements, the probability of treatment exposure is invariably different across time, which requires application of time-varying weights on the unit of analysis (e.g., individual subjects). So may I know your opinion about it.

I have not an incredible amount of experience with the issues of time-varying covariates in a GEE, I primarily encountered it in survival models (where for example the Cox model can handle this nicely), but I saw you already made a separate question for this new topic, so I will let others with more expertise in this problem help you maybe :) Hope I could already help you a little bit anyway!

@
Mathemagician777, thank you so much for your time
